# Junit5: Expect nested exception

Tags: junit5, nested-exceptions

How does JUnit 5 allow to check for a nested exception? I'm looking for something similar to what could be done in JUnit 4 with the help of a `@org.junit.Rule`, as shown in the following snippet:

```
class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void checkForNestedException() {

        // a JPA exception will be thrown, with a nested LazyInitializationException
        expectedException.expectCause(isA(LazyInitializationException.class));

        Sample s = sampleRepository.findOne(id);

        // not touching results triggers exception
        sampleRepository.delete(s);
    }
}
```

Edit as per comment:

`Assertions.assertThrows(LazyInitializationException.class)` does not work in JUnit 5, since `LazyInitializationException` is the nested exception (cause) of `JpaSystemException`.

Only the check for the outer exception can be made, which does not work as desired:

```
// assertThrows does not allow checking for nested LazyInitializationException
Assertions.assertThrows(JpaSystemException.class, () -> {

    Sample s = sampleRepository.getOne(id);

    // not touching results triggers exception
    sampleRepository.delete(s);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried assertThrows(..)? If so, what part didn’t work as expected?

Comment: @johanneslink assertThrows() only checks for the outer exception, but not for nested exception, see edited question for sample code.

Comment: assertThrows() returns the actual exception, which you can then use to do any assertions you like, eg getting its cause and check that.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to johanneslink, the solution is actually simple:

```
// assertThrows returns the thrown exception (a JpaSystemException)
Exception e = Assertions.assertThrows(JpaSystemException.class, () -> {

    Sample s = sampleRepository.getOne(id);

    // not touching results triggers exception
    sampleRepository.delete(s);
});

// Now the cause of the thrown exception can be checked
assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceof LazyInitializationException);
```